# How to access item in a Collection

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, collections, key

I have two collections.

First Collection is all descendants (not children) from root item, flat structure, in other words, ALL items in my DB in flat organization:

```
$descendants = $root->getDescendants();
```

I go through this collection using foreach:

```
foreach ($descendants as $key => &$item) {}
```

For each item, I do some magic, but then, I need to project this magic to only this item's descendants (not children) (which is subset of $descendants items, same items!).

I went ahead, got sub-descendants:

```
$itemDescendants = $item->getDescendants();
foreach ($itemDescendants as $key => &$item) {
    //modify $item, but in $descendants Collection
}
```

I know, $key in first foreach !== $key in second foreach.

How can I access $item (and get its $key) in $descendants Collection for editing, meaning, I change properties directly in $descendants Collection, which I return at the end of function?

I need a $item's $key from $descendants so I am able to modify it directly in $descendants:

```
$descendants[$key]->user_permissions = array();
```

I looked at the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods), closest is search, but doesnt work:

```
$childItem = $descendants->search($item);
```

Full code looks something like this:

```
$descendants = $root->getDescendants();
foreach ($descendants as $key => &$item) {
    $itemDescendants = $item->getDescendants();

    foreach ($itemDescendants as $key => &$childItem) {

        $mainChildItem = $descendants->search($childItem); //I would need to get a key ($childKey), not item..
        $user_permissions = array();
        //check if permissions are already set
        if(!empty($mainChildItem->permissions)){
            $permissions = $mainChildItem->permissions;
        }

        $user_permissions['all'] = ($user_permissions['all'] !== 0) ? $contentPermission['all'] : $user_permissions['all'];
        $user_permissions['view'] = ($user_permissions['view'] !== 0) ? $contentPermission['view'] : $user_permissions['view'];

        $descendants[$childKey]->user_permissions = array(); //missing $childKey
    }

}
return $descendants;
```

Comment: Can you show the full code you tried, to see how you encapsulate the foreach loops? From what i'm reading this seem very straight forward, but that can be because i don't understand the context between the two loops.

Comment: I have edited full code into OP.

Comment: But in your first loop you loop through descendants and define a single descendant as $item, this is still accessible in the next foreach loop so you would able to do $item = ->user_permissions = array(); Also assuming descendants is an object then there is no reason to define it as a reference as objects are always references

Comment: True about object's references, but I'm trying to access objects that are in the same collection but I only know them from second Collection, $itemDescendants.. I'm not modifying $item from $descendants, but items in $descendants, that are listed in $itemDescendants.

Comment: Ok i think i got it kinda. So the child object will be the same as the descendants, but you do not now the location. Is they both an Laravel model?

Comment: Yes, both are Laravel models and yes, I do not know the location, since I can only list descendants from one item at the time, then need to find them "main collection", modify them (still in the main collection) and then return this "main collection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, probably not optimal solution, I go through $descendants and save keys on item->id indexes:

```
foreach($descendants as $key=>$item){
    $descendantsKeys[$item->id] = $key;
}
```

And when I want to access specific item in $descendants, I use this array to search for a key.

```
$itemKey = $descendantsKeys[$childItem->id];
```

And then save this item in main Collection $descendants:

```
$descendants[$itemKey]->user_permissions = array();
```

I bet there is a more optimal way, but need to continue with development..